# symfony2 login keep saying Bad credentials

Tags: symfony

Hello I followed this tutorial:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

My security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        modules\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    test: { password: test }
        user_db:
            entity: { class: modulesUserBundle:User }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider: user_db
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"
                provider: in_memory
            form_login: ~

            logout:
                path:   _demo_logout
                target: _demo
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin, roBad credentialsles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

In database I have this:

users:

```
(id, username, salt, password, email, is_active)
(1,'admin','123456','7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc264','admin@modules.com',1)
(2,'bruno','123456','7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc264','mail@gmail.com',1)
```

roles:

```
(id, name, role)
(1,'Admin','ROLE_ADMIN')
(2,'User','ROLE_USER')
```

user_role:

```
(user_id, role_id)
(1,1)
(2,2)
```

Everytime I try to login with one user from DB I got "Bad credentials".
But if I login with 'test' user, defined in in_memory, no problem

I think the error is in my security.yml. But what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked log file?

Answer (score 1):

How have you registered this users in the DB? I can see users passwords in plain text, so i suppose that in the login process it's enconding the password with your config and after the hole proccess encoded pass != db pass, so it cant do the login. Encode DB passwords and i'm sure everithing will be ok
If you are loading fixtures, use $user->setPlainPassword('pass') to store user's password, compare db value with the new one, look how different they are
I hope it helps you

Comment: I'm using salt and password with the same SHA1, because I'm not sure about the salt. post edit

Answer (score 0):

fixed:
security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        modules\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: modulesUserBundle:User }

    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider: administrators
            form_login: ~

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```